# Reading in a list is only showing half of the array when printing to console

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have a list I am reading in and I want to have printed to console. The list is read in, it gets the accurate count, which in this case is 17 names, however will only print 11 of them.  I have an option to make the names be listed in ascending or descending alphabetical and it will still only  read in the first 11.

```js
var myLists = element.all(By.css("[data-bind='text: name']"));
//have also tried these ways: they work however still not full list
//var myLists = element.all(by.css('.name'));
//var myLists = element.all(by.css('td.name > span'));

this.readsInRoomName = function() {

  browser.driver.get('http://iplan-qa.meetingmatrix.com/Apps/CapacityChart/ACC2833/auto/auto');
  browser.driver.sleep(3000);
  //clicking button to make name order descending
  element.all(by.css("[data-bind='text: displayName, visible: displayName']")).first().click();
  element.all(by.css("[data-bind='text: displayName, visible: displayName']")).first().click();
  browser.driver.sleep(3000);
  //counting and printing the list
  myLists.count().then(function(count) {
    console.log(count);
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      myLists.get(i).getText().then(function(text) {
        console.log(" here are the names desc: " + text);
      });
    }
  });
};
```

The results: 
 -here are the names desc: Picasso III
 -here are the names desc: Picasso II-III
 -here are the names desc: Picasso II
 -here are the names desc: Picasso I-II
 -here are the names desc: Picasso I
 -here are the names desc: Picasso I-III
 -here are the names desc: Paul Klee
 -here are the names desc: Monet
 -here are the names desc: Kandinsky
 -here are the names desc: Joseph Beuys
 -here are the names desc: Hundertwasser
 -here are the names desc:
 -here are the names desc:
 -here are the names desc:
 -here are the names desc:
 -here are the names desc:
 -here are the names desc:

The results: 
 -here are the names asce: Andy Warhol
 -here are the names asce: Boardroom Pullman
 -here are the names asce: Chagall
 -here are the names asce: Chill out Space
 -here are the names asce: Christo
 -here are the names asce: Dali
 -here are the names asce: Hundertwasser
 -here are the names asce: Joseph Beuys
 -here are the names asce: Kandinsky
 -here are the names asce: Monet
 -here are the names asce: Paul Klee
 -here are the names asce:
 -here are the names asce:
 -here are the names asce:
 -here are the names asce:
 -here are the names asce:
 -here are the names asce:

The html is the same for every name, which can be seen below.

```html
<div class="cc-meeting-spaces-wrapper non-selectable jspScrollable" data-bind="jScrollPane: {}" style="overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; width: 1440px;" tabindex="0">

  <div class="jspContainer" style="width: 1440px; height: 336px;">

    <div class="jspPane" style="padding: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1424px;">

      <table id="spacesList" class="cc-meeting-spaces-list resizable theme-meeting-spaces-list" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: meetingSpaces, highlight: {}">

          <!--

     ko if: capacity.hasNonZero() 

    -->
          <tr class="selected" data-bind="click: $root.showCapacity, css: { 'selected': $data === $root.selectedSpace() && !$root.capacityLoaded() }">

            <td class="name">
              <span data-bind="text: name">

            Andy Warhol

        </span>
            </td>
            <td class="" data-bind="text: dimensions"></td>
            <td class="" data-bind="text: ceilingHeight"></td>
            <td class="cc-area"></td>
            <!--

     ko ifnot: showCapacities 

    -->
            <!--

     /ko 

    -->
            <!--

     ko if: showCapacities 

    -->
            <td class="cc-capacity" title="Theater" data-style="theater" data-bind="text: capacity.theater"></td>
            <td class="cc-capacity" title="Classroom" data-style="classroom" data-bind="text: capacity.classroom"></td>
            <td class="cc-capacity" title="Banquet" data-style="banquet" data-bind="text: capacity.banquet"></td>
            <td class="cc-capacity" title="Conference" data-style="conference" data-bind="text: capacity.conference"></td>
            <td class="cc-capacity" title="UShape" data-style="uShape" data-bind="text: capacity.uShape"></td>
            <td class="cc-capacity" title="Hollow Square" data-style="hollowSquare" data-bind="text: capacity.hollowSquare"></td>
            <td class="cc-capacity" title="Reception" data-style="reception" data-bind="text: capacity.reception"></td>
            <!--

     /ko 

    -->

          </tr>
          <!--

 /ko 

-->

          <!--

 ko if: capacity.hasNonZero() 

-->

          <tr class="" data-bind="click: $root.showCapacity, css: { 'selected': $data === $root.selectedSpace() && !$root.capacityLoaded() }">

            <td class="name">
              <span data-bind="text: name">

            Boardroom Pullman

        </span>
            </td>
            <td class="" data-bind="text: dimensions"></td>
            <td class="" data-bind="text: ceilingHeight"></td>
            <td class="cc-area"></td>
            <!--

     ko ifnot: showCapacities 

    -->
            <!--

     /ko 

    -->
            <!--

     ko if: showCapacities 

    -->
            <td class="cc-capacity" title="Theater" data-style="theater" data-bind="text: capacity.theater"></td>
            <td class="cc-capacity" title="Classroom" data-style="classroom" data-bind="text: capacity.classroom"></td>
            <td class="cc-capacity" title="Banquet" data-style="banquet" data-bind="text: capacity.banquet"></td>
            <td class="cc-capacity" title="Conference" data-style="conference" data-bind="text: capacity.conference"></td>
            <td class="cc-capacity" title="UShape" data-style="uShape" data-bind="text: capacity.uShape"></td>
            <td class="cc-capacity" title="Hollow Square" data-style="hollowSquare" data-bind="text: capacity.hollowSquare"></td>
            <td class="cc-capacity" title="Reception" data-style="reception" data-bind="text: capacity.reception"></td>
            <!--

     /ko 

    -->

          </tr>
```

Any help would be fantastic I'm lost

**I switched to another list of names with 28 in the array, still only reading in/printing 11 of them.**

[image]

The answer:

```js
        myLists.count().then(function(count) {
          console.log(count);
          for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", myLists.get(i).getWebElement());
            myLists.get(i).getText().then(function(text) {
              console.log(text);
            });
          }
        });
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
        myLists.count().then(function(count) {
          console.log(count);
          for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", myLists.get(i).getWebElement());
            myLists.get(i).getText().then(function(text) {
              console.log(text);
            });
          }
        });
```

I need to scroll down line by line in order to make each name element viewable.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using [`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map) to get a promise resolving into an array of texts:

```
myLists.map(function (elm) {
    return elm.getText();
}).then(function (texts) {
    console.log(texts);
});
```

What might also help is to *scroll into view of the latest record in the array*:

```
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", myLists.last().getWebElement());
```

Or, add a wait to *wait for all of the texts to be non-empty*:

```
browser.wait(
    function () {
        return myLists.count().then(function (all) {
            return myLists.filter(function (elm) {
                return elm.getText().then(function (text) {
                    return text !== "";
                });
            }).count().then(function (filteredCount) {
                return all === filteredCount;
            });
        });
        return 
    },
    5000
);
```

You can also try combining `map()` with the scroll into view:

```
myLists.each(function (elm) {
    browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elm.getWebElement());
}).map(function (elm) {
    return elm.getText();
}).then(function (texts) {
    console.log(texts);
})
```

Comment: that returned: *[ 'Andy Warhol', 'Boardroom Pullman', 'Chagall', 'Chill out Space', 'Christo', 'Dali', 'Hundertwasser', 'Joseph Beuys', 'Kandinsky', 'Monet', 'Paul Klee', '', '', '', '', '', '' ] isnt that strange... –

Comment: @NicolePhillips okay, updated the answer, check it out.

Comment: I got a Failed: wait timed out after 7152ms error.  I was wondering if it has something to do with what is seen on screen.  I posted a pic of another array of names and noticed it reads in until you cannot see anymore names on the screen, a scroll function may do it... I however have no idea how to do it, per usual, noob status.

Comment: it was the scroll. The non-empty timed out for me.  I was wondering, some of my pages have like 60 names, how the heck would it know to keep scrolling to read it?

Comment: @NicolePhillips probably the only visible data is loaded, and, once you scroll, more data appears.

Comment: @Alexce I got it!  I used a mixture of you and Barrets code, I have it scrolling down line by line.

Comment: Would you know how to do your map function that scrolls down element by element as the text is read in? Like the answer but using the map.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if the [each](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each) suffix would work in this instance.

```
myLists.each(function(element, index) {
  // Will print 0 First, 1 Second, 2 Third.
  browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView()', element.getWebElement());
  element.getText().then(function (text) {

    console.log(index, " here are the names desc: " + text);
  });
});
```

**UPDATE:** added a scroll into view before printing the text

Comment: it returned the same array as Alecxe suggested. This is just blowing my mind it makes no sense to me what so ever

Comment: I think I know whats going on.. I think since these are the only names visible on the screen until I move my scroll bar it is only reading in those names.  Posting a screenshot, any idea how to go about that scrolling and finishing reading off list?

Comment: I added a scroll into view before getting the text and printing it

Comment: that did scroll however it just printed out the middle of the array.  Getting somewhere, now just to get it to scroll down with every name pass one by one.

Comment: I have it scrolling line by line, a mix of yours and Alecxe's code.  I appreciate you two as both of you are the only ones really answering my questions, you know your stuff.